# get line number within matcher.find() using matcher.start()

Tags: java, regex

I am using `while(matcher.find())` to loop through and retrieve things from a file. I was wondering how would I get a line number from within this loop, if I knew the index of what I have found is at `matcher.start()`.

I am confused, could someone please explain?

```
 String expr = "<[^<?!>]+>";
     String[] response = new String[5];

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(expr);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(xmlDocument);
        while (m.find()) {
        //  System.out.println(m.group() + " located at " + m.start());
       //   txtMatches.append(m.group() + " located at " + m.start() + "\n");
            if (itemStack.getCount() == 0 && m.group().contains("</")) {
                response[0] = "Orphan closing tag" ; 
                response[1] = stripUnwantedChars(m.group(), true); 
                response[2] =  String.valueOf(m.start()); //right here is where i want to return line number
                return response; 
            }
        //rest of code
```

`itemStack` is a stack of pushed matches and then I am comparing them to see if there is no more items in the stack but there is a match with a closing tag.

Comment: Are you constructing a separate Matcher for each line, or one for the entire contents of the file, or something else? Some code would be nice.

Comment: no not separate matcher for each line. one for the entire file right now.  and loop through finding all text using this regex = "<[^<?!>]+>" let me see if I can simplify some code to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separately create an array of the indexes where each line starts, and then you can use this array together with the index returned by `start()` to figure out which line your match is on. A binary search of that line index array would do nicely. You could actually create this list of line indexes also by using a regex that matches a line end (matching just '\n' would be fine) and then starting each line at the next character.

Comment: thanks Ernest but I don't quite understand, I posted some code up to better explain what I was trying to do.

Comment: Before running the above code, run some similar code which finds all the line endings in the file. Keep their file indexes in a list or array. Now you have a list of the first character offset of each line. Then when you're running your code above, and you call matcher.start() to get an offset and you want to know the line number, you just search through that array until you find the largest entry smaller than your offset. The index of that entry is the line number. There's really no other way to do this!

Comment: okay thanks you have confirmed what I was just going to try. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a reverse method to get line number by creating a region from 0 to character number returned from start().

For example,

```
class MatchTest {
public static void main(String...args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("source.txt");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(buffer);
        String data = new String(buffer);
        fis.close();


        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(args[0]);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            out.println(matcher.group());
            out.println(getLine(data, matcher.start()));


        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static int getLine(String data, int start) {
    int line = 1;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\n");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
    matcher.region(0, start);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        line++;
    }
    return(line);
}
```

}

Here, the getLine method will return line number.